# Setting OSGi storage directoy (org.osgi.framework.storage) does not work in Maven triggered JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, junit, osgi, equinox

In my code I start multiple OSGi frameworks using `EquinoxFactory`. By setting the property `"org.osgi.framework.storage"` to `"@user.home/osgi-frameworks/framework-x"`, where `x` is different for every framework, each framework uses a different directory:

```
frameworkProperties.put("osgi.clean", "true");
frameworkProperties.put("osgi.console", "true");
frameworkProperties.put("org.osgi.framework.storage", 
                        "@user.home/osgi-frameworks/osgi-framework-" 
                        + numberOfFramework);       

framework = new EquinoxFactory().newFramework(frameworkProperties)
```

This works perfectly when running the actual application. Also the JUnit tests in the IDE run without any problems.

However, when I start the Maven build for my project, the JUnit tests fail since all frameworks use the same directory (`"osgi-frameworks/framework-0"`).

I added logging to the application to check whether the property `"org.osgi.framework.storage"` does really have different value in the OSGi property map. Everything looks fine in the log, but when checking the file space, only one directory has been created.

Since I would like to include the application in Jenkins, I would rather not skip the tests.

Has anyone an idea what could be wrong? Do I have to set other parameters for the framework? Is there any considerable difference between Junit in the IDE and in Maven?

Comment: Where have you added the logging? Are you sure you are logging the property-values that are actually used by the framework?

Comment: Just curious, I am wanting to start headless builds with osgi and rcp apps. How are you going about this build process, are you using maven integration with OSIG?